# Jackson JsonSchema - Object as string in schema

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I'm using `ComparableQuantity` from [JSR 385 reference implementation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.units/indriya/1.1) - this is not a case, just want to mention that subtype is generic and I cannot modify it.

The case is that I am generating a Json schema with [Jackson JsonSchemaModule](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema).
Currently, what I am receiving from that schema is of course something like below:

```
{
  "weight": {
    "type": "object",
    "id": "Mass>",
    "required": true,
    "properties": {
      "value": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "unit": {
        "type": "object",
        "id": "Mass>",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ofc, this does not give me a lot - it is too expressive.
I already have a parsers which can create my values from string (with validation) and serialize it also to string (10m will be in json just "10 m"), and I would want to have the same schema, with pattern, for example:

```
{
  "weight": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": "[\\d,.]+\\s*(kg|t)",
    "required": true
  }
}
```

I know that `Jdk8JacksonModule` can make something similiar with `Optional`, but When I saw `Jdk8OptionalBeanPropertyWriter`, I have passed - even not sure if it is correct place to look for.

Also, I think it is possible to use `ObjectMapper$acceptJsonFormatVisitor`, maybe something with `SchemaFactoryWrapper#expectObjectFormat` - not sure.

What I have noticed is that when I add `ComparableQuantity` serialization module to Schema serializer (which is actually class serialization from schema), it will then return

```
{
  "weight": {
    "type": "any",
    "required": true
  }
}
```

so maybe this is some way...

Any example would be nice :).

Answer (score 1):

I've finished with overriding method `JsonSerializer#acceptJsonFormatVisitor` where I call `visitor.expectStringFormat(type)`, and also, to add a pattern I added `visitor` in constructor of `JsonSchemaGenerator`.

This visitor bases on `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.customProperties.ValidationSchemaFactoryWrapper`, but instead of `expectObjectFormat` overrides `expectStringFormat` of course.